# Transposing a pandas dataframe with multiple columns to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset in the following format

```
source  adset     date  impression  click   spend
fb      abc       1/1/19    100 140 20
fb      abc       1/2/19    200 130 40
cl      xyz       1/1/19    300 200 50
cl      xyz       1/2/19    500 200 50
```

how to use pandas to get the format as below?

```
source  adset        kpi    1/1/19  1/2/19
fb     abc         impression   100 200
fb     abc         click    140 130
fb     abc         spend    20  40
cl     abc         impression   300 500
cl     abc         click    200 200
cl     abc         spend    50  50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['source','adset','date'])
        .rename_axis('kpi', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .unstack(level=2)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
date source adset         kpi  1/1/19  1/2/19
0        cl   xyz  impression     300     500
1        cl   xyz       click     200     200
2        cl   xyz       spend      50      50
3        fb   abc  impression     100     200
4        fb   abc       click     140     130
5        fb   abc       spend      20      40
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt(['source','adset','date'], var_name='kpi')
        .pivot_table(index=['source','adset', 'kpi'], columns='date', values='value')
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
date source adset         kpi  1/1/19  1/2/19
0        cl   xyz       click     200     200
1        cl   xyz  impression     300     500
2        cl   xyz       spend      50      50
3        fb   abc       click     140     130
4        fb   abc  impression     100     200
5        fb   abc       spend      20      40
```